# Brief / debrief, flammable / inflammable — is there a term for pairs of words that appear to be antonyms but aren't?

Tags: antonyms, auto-antonyms

Is there a word for a pair of words that would appear to be antonyms from their construction, but actually have the same or similar meanings?

For example, *brief* / *debrief*.  From [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/oct/11/michel-barnier-meets-brexit-secretary-after-uks-positive-talks-with-ireland):

> A spokeswoman for the European commission said Barnier would debrief ambassadors and MEPs on the European parliament’s Brexit steering group.

The meaning wouldn't change much if it instead said:

> A spokeswoman for the European commission said Barnier would brief ambassadors and MEPs on the European parliament’s Brexit steering group.

One can debate on a subtle change of meaning and as to whether the second use is actually correct (some dictionaries state that the verb *brief* means to inform ones superiors specifically), but we can probably agree that *debrief* is not, in this context, the antonym of *brief*, despite the prefix *de-* usually indicating a reversal (such as in *decode*, *decompress*, *demystify*, *detoxicate*).

Another example may be *flammable* and *inflammable*.  The prefix *in-* often indicates a reversal (*incredible*, *invisible*, *inalienable*), but *inflammable* is rather a stronger version of *flammable* (*intoxicate* is not an antonym of *toxicate*, but doesn't have a similar meaning either).

Is there a word for the situation where two words would appear to be antonyms but aren't?  I was thinking of [auto-antonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym), but that is a single word having two opposite meanings.  Here, we have two seemingly opposite words having (almost) the same meaning, which is related but not quite the same.

Comment: One meaning of _brief_ is to give someone final instructions for a mission; _debriefing_ is their report after they have carried it out. So presumably M. Barnier was reporting on discussions that had already happened.

Comment: But *brief* and *debrief* ***are*** opposites. At least in one sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford In one sense, but not in all senses.